# The problem in data transmission between flink and kafka running on python in windows environment

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-flink, pyflink

I am a beginner of flink and kafka. I started zookeeper and kafka in windows system, and tried to test the example 'Kafka With Json Format' in official website in python environment.

```
import logging
import sys

from pyflink.common import Types
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.datastream.connectors.kafka import FlinkKafkaProducer, FlinkKafkaConsumer
from pyflink.datastream.formats.json import JsonRowSerializationSchema, JsonRowDeserializationSchema


# Make sure that the Kafka cluster is started and the topic 'test_json_topic' is
# created before executing this job.
def write_to_kafka(env):
    type_info = Types.ROW([Types.INT(), Types.STRING()])
    ds = env.from_collection(
        [(1, 'hi'), (2, 'hello'), (3, 'hi'), (4, 'hello'), (5, 'hi'), (6, 'hello'), (6, 'hello')],
        type_info=type_info)

    serialization_schema = JsonRowSerializationSchema.Builder() \
        .with_type_info(type_info) \
        .build()
    kafka_producer = FlinkKafkaProducer(
        topic='test_json_topic',
        serialization_schema=serialization_schema,
        producer_config={'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092', 'group.id': 'test_group'}
    )

    # note that the output type of ds must be RowTypeInfo
    ds.add_sink(kafka_producer)
    env.execute()


def read_from_kafka(env):
    deserialization_schema = JsonRowDeserializationSchema.Builder() \
        .type_info(Types.ROW([Types.INT(), Types.STRING()])) \
        .build()
    kafka_consumer = FlinkKafkaConsumer(
        topics='test_json_topic',
        deserialization_schema=deserialization_schema,
        properties={'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092', 'group.id': 'test_group_1'}
    )
    kafka_consumer.set_start_from_earliest()

    env.add_source(kafka_consumer).print()
    env.execute()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO, format="%(message)s")

    env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
    env.add_jars("file:///path/to/flink-sql-connector-kafka-1.15.0.jar")

    print("start writing data to kafka")
    write_to_kafka(env)

    print("start reading data from kafka")
    read_from_kafka(env)
```

I wrote data from flink to kafka and read it, but when I executed `env.execute()` in function read_from_data, the following error appeared: 'Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create stage bundle factory! INFO:root:Initializing Python harness: C:\\Users\\hp.conda\\envs\\myenv\\lib\\site-packages\\pyflink\\fn_execution\\beam\\beam_boot.py --id=5-1 --provision_endpoint=localhost:58376 INFO:root:Starting up Python harness in loopback mode.'

I don't know how to solve it. I used Kafka Tool to monitor and found that data can be successfully written into topic, but it cannot be read from topic. The offset in consumer test_group_1 remains unchanged, but the lag will increase. Hope to get help to make the program run normally and output the results.

Comment: `file:///` paths are specific to Unix systems, not Windows; you're missing `c:` as part of that I think. Also, try running these as two separate apps since the producer and consumer may start on different threads at the same time

Comment: My add_jars has been changed to a path suitable for Windows, and I have tried to run the write and read operations in two files separately, but the same error still appears. I observed that the data can be successfully written into topic (the write file can be executed successfully), but the data still cannot be read from topic.